# iOS - Add Tap Gesture to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have problem with add a Tap Gesture to my UITextField. Below code:

```
@IBAction func hanldeTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    println("works")
}
```

This action is associated with Tap Gesture Recognizer. In my TextField I have defined `gestureRecognizer` in `OutletCollections`. In my guess it should works. In described configuration gesture works e.x. for button or custom view.

Can you tell my what could go wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UITextField has `delegate methods`, you might want to consider implementing those. Or just add action event to your textfield.

For example in `viewDidLoad`

```
textField.addTarget(self, action:Selector("textDidBeginEditing"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin)
```

Then implement this:

```
func textDidBeginEditing(sender:UITextField) -> Void
{
   // handle begin editing event
}
```

Comment: Why in UITextField I can't just use a UITapGesture?

Comment: I want to tap once on this text and show a popup view, and when a tap twice I want to hide it. I don't think I can manage this that way. I thinkI have to create a custom view.

Comment: I agree to your last sentence, better idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the textfields delegate, you can use;

`optional func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)`

or

`optional func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool`

etc

Answer (score 1):

```
textField.addTarget(self, action:#selector(textDidBeginEditing), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

Adding to the accepted answer

Don't forget to add '#' before selector (with small s) i.e. #selector

`textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidBeginEditing), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin)`

And do add @objc before the function. like

`@objc func textDidBeginEditing(sender:UITextField) -> Void`