# tap on UITextField not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift3

I read a lot try to find a way to handle uitextfield click but nothing working for me

What I want:

I want add tap on UITextField and open dialog

What I tried:

```
class CreateMessagesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
//        testField.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        testView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        testField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTapped(_:)), for: .touchDown)
    }

    func onTapped(_ sender : UITextField){

        print("Hello World")
    }

    func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Hello World")
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried 2 ways:

1. UITapGestureRecognizer
2. selector

Just for the test I add simple UIView to make sure tap is working and it worked.

Why it doesn't work on uiTextField? Is there anything I have missed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get UITextField Tap Event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045095/how-to-get-uitextfield-tap-event)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - Add Tap Gesture to UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675976/ios-add-tap-gesture-to-uitextfield)

Comment: try to disable the selection for text field. or without using gesture apple will provide didBeginEditing delegate method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add UITapGestureRecognizer to UITextView without blocking textView touches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858908/add-uitapgesturerecognizer-to-uitextview-without-blocking-textview-touches)

Comment: why not use textfield delegate method and check if this textfield then open dialog

Comment: remove textfield delegate and check once

Comment: your condition is working fine for me

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how to remove delegate from textfield?

Comment: @fish40 - on your storyboard, just remove the delegate in connection inspector

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik there is no delegate there see the link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fujlorfvuymzqdw/Screenshot%202017-02-07%2014.18.10.png?dl=0

Comment: @fish40 - wait i will check and update you

Comment: @fish40 - for testing purpose add one uialertview inside `onTapped(_ sender : UITextField)` and check once

Comment: same behaviour  testField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTapped(_:)), for: .touchDown). also I unchecked user interactionj enabled from storyboard

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding gesture recognizer you can write the code for opening dialog in

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    openDialog()//Function which will open the dialog
    return false
}
```

I think it should have the same effect as you want.

Answer (score 1):

1)add gesture recognizer:

```
let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(someFunc))
tapGR.delegate = self
textField.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)
```

2)make sure that you allow your tap handler when it is necessary:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true //or add your custom check here if you need
}
```

Without of the second part you get a buggy `textField` where sometimes tap gesture doesn't work, sometimes default gestures not handled!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to achieve this. You should conform your view controller class to `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement `textFieldDidBeginEditing`in your class.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
       //show popup here
}
```

If you are having multiple text fields, assign a tag to your text field in the storyboard(or in the code) to recognize the text field.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
// check your tag here
   if textField.tag == 0 {
            //show your popup here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add GestureRecognizer to `UITextField` superview and check if help:

```
testField.superview.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: superview is not a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I created sample one for your question both Swift and Objective C but it not working.I used the Tap Gesture recognizer code for textField but it not even called.

Not Worked below Code in Swift and Objective C

**Swift**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(handleTaponTextField(_:)))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tap.delegate = self
txtFldTapMe.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
txtFldTapMe.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func handleTaponTextField(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("Tap is handled here!")
}
```

**Objective C**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.delegate = self;
txtfldTapME.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[txtfldTapME addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

func handleTaponTextField(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("Tap is handled here!")
}
```

Then I tried with below addTarget action method for textField and it works fine.

Worked below Code in Swift and Objective C

**Swift**

```
txtFldTapMe.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldEditDidBegin(_:)), for: .editingDidBegin)

func textFieldEditDidBegin(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("Text editing begin here!")
}
```

See the methods

[image]

You should use above methods of textField

**Objective C**

```
[txtfldTapME addTarget:self action:@selector(editingDidBeginStarted:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];   

-(void)editingDidBeginStarted:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
  NSLog(@"Editing started here");
}
```

See the below textField methods

[image]

Comment: what does your `tap.delegate = self` do? It seems `UITapGestureRecognizer` doesn't work properly because of something you have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText), for: .editingChanged)
    addSubview(view)

@objc func didChangeText(textField:UITextField) {
    let str = textField.text
        //your functionality here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible. Because Textfield delegate method call.

Comment: Link is working as I want 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42086875/2264402